# How to connect to using wpa_supplicant on ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

I'm trying to connect to wifi using `wpa_cli` on *ubuntu 10.04*.

I test wifi using `network-manager-applet` in ubuntu.

Wifi driver is installed on system correctly.

First I make a file in the place `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
network={
    ssid="367307-Maxis Fibre Internet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    proto=RSN
    psk="429140AEFF"
}
```

Next, I excute the following command in terminal.

```
wpa_supplicant -B -ira0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && dhclient ra0
```

And I received the errors.

```
There is already a pid file /var/run/dhclient.pid with pid 3703
```

Killed old client process, removed PID file

```
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.3
Copyright 2004-2009 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Listening on LPF/ra0/44:33:4c:c1:16:ee
Sending on   LPF/ra0/44:33:4c:c1:16:ee
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.121 on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.121 on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
DHCPDISCOVER on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
DHCPDISCOVER on ra0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
No DHCPOFFERS received.
Trying recorded lease 192.168.1.121
PING 192.168.1.254 (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 192.168.1.254 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
------------------------------
```

Why I can't obtain the ip address from dhcp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to do what you want, you have to be the only one to command the `wpa_supplicant` and `dhclient`. So you have to kill every *network managers* that you have. So you have to kill your `network-manager-applet`.

Then, your file `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` have to include the `ctrl_interface` information to be able to command the `wpa_supplicant` with the `wpa_cli`. Moreover the `proto` statement is not mandatory in the `network` description, and can be an error source (if you don't known exactly the AP proto). So use this file instead:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
    ssid="367307-Maxis Fibre Internet"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    psk="429140AEFF"
}
```

Then you can run the `wpa_supplicant` daemon:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i ra0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
```

You can also run it as an normal application to be able to see debug output (you will have to open a new tty):

```
wpa_supplicant -dd -i ra0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wext
```

Then check the wifi connection status with the `wpa_cli`:

```
wpa_cli -i ra0 status
```

In the output you **must** see `wpa_state=COMPLETED` before continue.

When the Wi-Fi link is in `COMPELETED` state. Run the dhcp server to get an ip address:

```
dhclient ra0
```

If all is OK, you will have a fully enable IP link over Wi-Fi :D

To stop all of this, just kill the `dhclient` and the `wpa_supplicant`.

*NOTE: You should think to update your ubuntu version, you are 4 years late and 2 [LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)...*